# Why is isinstance() returning different values for the same data depending on implementation?

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, isinstance

I have a pandas dataframe `df` where I want to check the datatypes

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df
>>> a1    a2    a3    a4
0   5     10.08 22.9  50.45
1   25    13.80 43.0  NaN
2   2     8.30  15.0  17.00
print(df.dtypes)
>>>
a1        int64
a2     float64
a3     float64
a4     float64
dtype: object
```

I have a function which checks the datatypes, namely whether a value is a scalar or not

```
def isScalar(a):
    if isinstance(a, (int, float, np.int64, np.float64)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Now, if I run

```
df.applymap(isScalar)
>>> a1      a2      a3      a3      
0   False   True    True    True
1   False   True    True    True
2   False   True    True    True
```

we see that the `a1` column is all False, which contradicts if I run individual values through `isScalar()`

```
print(type(df.a1[1]))
>>> numpy.int64
print(isScalar(df.a1[1]))
>>> True
```

What is going on here? The values of `a1` returned by `df.applymap(isScalar)` should all be True.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue.  I am getting all `True` values

Comment: It turns out this was a python version issue. I have python 2.7 and python 3.7 environments, both with the same versions of pandas as numpy (0.23.4 and 1.15.4 respectively). In python 2.7 I get the error asked in the question. In python 3.7 I don't. It would still be good to know why this happens though.

Comment: I can't reproduce even on 2.7: https://repl.it/repls/VictoriousQuickwittedTruespace